# What happens to the global variables in shared library when dlclose is called on it?

Tags: c, dll, shared-libraries, dlopen

If a shared library (or a DLL) is being used through dlopen and dlclose mechanism and if the shared library created has some global variables whose memory comes from the heap, then what will happen to those variables and the memory when dlclose is called?

If in the same process, dlopen is called again, what will be the behaviour?

Comment: Global variables do *not* usually come from heap. Your question appears to use invalid assumptions.

Comment: @Employed Russian, I have a global pointer variable to which I am allocating memory from heap. What would happen to that? Also, if a normal static global variable is there, what will happen to that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `dlclose` reduces the reference count to zero and the library is actually unloaded, any future reloading of the library should reset all variables with static storage duration in the library to their original values.

However, if the library was opened more than once, all but the final call to `dlclose` will just decrement the reference count. Sometimes it may not be obvious whether a library was opened more than once, since it might have gotten loaded as a dependency of some other library without you knowing, unless it's a module local to your program, so it's probably not a good idea to rely on this "reset" behavior.

Employed Russian added:

> Even if the library is `dlopen()`ed and `dlclose()`d exactly once, and is not a dependency of something else, the act of referencing symbols from it (via `dlsym()`) will also increment the reference count (and make the library not unloadable); at least on Linux.

I have no idea if this information is accurate or not. In the future, please post new information as a comment or a new answer, not an edit to other people's answers. If you just edit someone else's answers, you make them take responsibility for the correctness of your answer, which they may not want.

Comment: @R, Thanks for the answer. You mean all global variables with static storage will be automatically reset? What about a global pointer to which memory has been allocated through malloc?

Comment: If you're asking whether that will leak memory, the answer is yes. The pointer will be lost. **Don't do that.** If your libraries need to keep global state, use one or more (possibly large) objects of static storage duration, not dynamic allocation. If the data is just a table of constants generated at runtime, write a script to generate them at compile-time instead and make them a `static const` array. You'll sacrifice (cheap) disk space and save lots of (valuable) memory.

Comment: Also note that there is an ugly workaround: have your library `dlopen` itself and throw away the pointer returned so that its reference count will never reach zero after it's been loaded once. But I wouldn't recommend doing this...

Comment: @R, Thanks a lot for your answers. They are very informative. : )